# How to not let a timer stop in nextJS when idle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Basically, I created a simple timer app with Next

https://sitstandtimer.vercel.app/

and I want it to just stay counting even if I'm not on the browser window. When I go to another window for about 5 minutes it stops counting, which is odd behavior. Here's the code for the Timer:

```html
const useTimer = (initialState = 0) => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(initialState)
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
    const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false)
    const countRef = useRef(null)
  
    const handleStart = () => {
      setIsActive(true)
      setIsPaused(true)
      countRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((timer) => timer + 1)
      }, 1000)
    }
  
    const handlePause = () => {
      clearInterval(countRef.current)
      setIsPaused(false)
    }
  
    const handleResume = () => {
      setIsPaused(true)
      countRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((timer) => timer + 1)
      }, 1000)
    }
  
    const handleReset = () => {
      clearInterval(countRef.current)
      setIsActive(false)
      setIsPaused(false)
      setTimer(0)
    }
  
    return { timer, isActive, isPaused, handleStart, handlePause, handleResume, handleReset, setTimer }
  }
```

Comment: Browsers can slow down intervals or even stop them when the page is not used. You also shouldn't trust that this `1000` will always be 1000 ms, it can differ. Better just save the start time and then calculate how much time passed since the last update.

Comment: Inactive/minimized/etc windows/tabs are different across browsers. The old workaround of using a WebWorker might still work. You can also do something w/ the absolute time within the interval callback for when the tab's JS was paused.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I used your solution and it worked marvelously. Can you do a proper answer so I can check the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already answered in the comment. Setting time elapsed instead of adding 1 is usually a better solution because browsers can slow down or disable intervals in the background.

```
const useTimer = (initialTime = 0) => {
    const [startTime, setStartTime) = useState(0);
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(initialState)
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
    const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false)
    const countRef = useRef(null)

    const startInterval = () => setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000)
      }, 1000)
    }
  
    const handleStart = () => {
      setStartTime(Date.now())
      setIsActive(true)
      setIsPaused(true)
      countRef.current = startInterval()
  
    const handlePause = () => {
      clearInterval(countRef.current)
      setIsPaused(false)
    }
  
    const handleResume = () => {
      setIsPaused(true)
      countRef.current = startInterval()
    }
  
    const handleReset = () => {
      clearInterval(countRef.current)
      setIsActive(false)
      setIsPaused(false)
      setTimer(0)
    }
  
    return { timer, isActive, isPaused, handleStart, handlePause, handleResume, handleReset, setTimer }
  }
```

Comment: There's a little bug here if `initialTime` != 0. It isn't used again and is overwritten right away. Rename it to `initialState` to match Question and line 3. Then the update should be `setTimer(initialTime + ((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000))`

Comment: @scottheckel you are right, feel free to edit my answer :)